# PyMongo Atlas Search not returning anything

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to do a full text search using Atlas for MongoDB. I'm doing this through the PyMongo driver in Python. I'm using the aggregate pipeline, and doing a $search but it seems to return nothing.

```
cursor = db.collection.aggregate([
    {"$search": {"text": {"query": "hello", "path": "text_here"}}},
    {"$project": {"file_name": 1}}
])

for x in cursor:
    print(x)
```

What I'm trying to achieve with this code is to search through a field in the collection called "text_here", and I'm searching for a term "hello" and returning all the results that contain that term and listing them by their "file_name". However, it returns nothing and I'm quite confused as this is almost identical to the example code on the documentation website. The only thing I could think of right now is that possible the path isn't correct and it can't access the field I've specified. Also, this code returns no errors, simply just returns nothing as I've tested by looping through cursor.

Comment: Atlas Search will be faster and better. Just a fact. Don't forget to include your index name if it is not default. Here's a great Python example if you need one: https://github.com/MarcusSorealheis/Flask_Tuts

Comment: The problem here looks like you may not have created a search index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only doing a find and project, you don't need an aggregate query, just a `find()`. The syntax you want is:

```
db.collection.find({'$text': {'$search': 'hello'}}, {'file_name': 1})
```

Equivalent using aggregate:

```
cursor = db.collection.aggregate([
    {'$match': {'$text': {'$search': 'hello'}}},
    {'$project': {'file_name': 1}}])
```

Worked example:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient, TEXT

db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']

db.collection.create_index([('text_here', TEXT)])
db.collection.insert_one({"text_here": "hello, is it me you're looking for", "file_name": "foo.bar"})

cursor = db.collection.find({'$text': {'$search': 'hello'}}, {'file_name': 1})

for item in cursor:
    print(item)
```

prints:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5fc81ce9a4a46710459de610'), 'file_name': 'foo.bar'}
```

Comment: Well you can just take the same syntax and poke it into an aggregate query. I've edited my answer to give an example.

Comment: Gotcha, that does seem to work but using that format, how would you be able to do boolean queries like 'AND'ing two searches together? I've found one way using the double quotes but I can't seem to find a command for it.

Comment: `$match` queries are "ANDed" by adding additional filter terms, e.g. `{'$match': {'$text': {'$search': 'hello'}, "file_name": "foo.bar"}}`

Comment: Yeah I seem to be able to solve it that way, but is there a way to get it done like this example? https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/queryString/ . It's more read-able when you're able to see the 'AND' and 'OR' in the query. Thanks so much.

Comment: No idea - never used it.

Comment: You should be using search for this. @steven what you are missing in that example is an index. Unless the value of the index name is `default` you need one. It should be fine otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I solved it by also passing the name of the index in the query. For example:

```
{ 
  index: "name_of_the_index",
  text: {
    query: 'john doe',
    path: 'name'
  }
}
```

I followed the tutorials but couldn't get any result back without specifying the "index" name. I wish this was mentioned in the documentation as mandatory.

Comment: So true, I cant believe it's not in the docs.